# PHP array_push error

Tags: php, pass-by-reference, array-push

My code is as below,

```
$products = array();
for($i=0; $i < sizeof($sales); $i++){
    if(!in_array($sales[$i]['Product']['product'], (array)$products)){
        $products = array_push((array)$products, $sales[$i]['Product']['product']);
    }           
}
```

I'm getting an error called **Fatal error:** Only variables can be passed by reference...

I'm using php5

Comment: $products = (array)$products; //this goes wrong in your method 
$products = array_push($products, $sales[$i]['Product']['product']);

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't use `array_push` like that, that's your basic problem. You're trying to fix an error you're producing by casting `$products` to an array, which causes a new error. You use `array_push` like this:

```
array_push($products, ...);
```

You do ***not*** assign the return value back to `$products`, because the return value is the new number of elements in the array, not the new array. So either:

```
array_push($products, $sales[$i]['Product']['product']);
```

or:

```
$products[] = $sales[$i]['Product']['product'];
```

**Not:**

```
$products = array_push($products, $sales[$i]['Product']['product']);
```

**and most certainly not:**

```
$products = array_push((array)$products, $sales[$i]['Product']['product']);
```

Please RTM: http://php.net/array_push

Answer (score 2):

The first parameter (`$products` in your case) has to be a reference, therefore a variable has to be passed. You now cast the variable to an array first and the result of that cast cannot be passed by reference since it is not assigned to a variable. You will have to assign it to a variable first or remove the cast.